# Id a partir do email inserido

Tags: python, django

Tenho um formulário apenas com a label email para o usuário preencher. Se o email já existe quero redirecioná-lo para a página de editar. Como faço para pegar o id do usuário por meio do email que ele digitou? Fiz um teste como demonstrado abaixo com o id 14 e está passando pra página certinho, só tenho que descobrir como pegar o id.

```
def email(request):
form = EmailForm(request.POST or None)
if form.is_valid():
    email = form.cleaned_data.get("email")
    try:
        profile = Perfil.objects.get(email=email, is_staff=False)
        print("email ja existe e nao staff")
        return redirect("cadastro:editar", id=profile.id)
    except:
        if not Perfil.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
            print("novo usuario")
            return redirect("/cadastro/cadastro")
        else:
            print("já entra no sistema")
            return redirect("/cadastro/login")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode buscar através da consulta que já está sendo feita no 'if', assim:

```
def email(request):
    form = EmailForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        email = form.cleaned_data.get("email")

        try:
            profile = Perfil.objects.get(email=email, is_staff=False)
            print("email ja existe e nao staff")
            return redirect("cadastro:editar", id=profile.id)
        except Perfil.DoesNotExist:
            print('email nao existe')
```

Comment: O filter retorna uma QuerySet, não tem como pegar o id usando filter, dá o seguinte erro: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'id'

Comment: Desculpe. Alterei o código acima. Troquei o .filter por .get

Comment: Realmente. O get retorna uma exception se o objeto não existir.
Alterei o código acima mais uma vez pra ajustar a exception.

Comment: Consegui Marcos! Agradeço a ajuda! Alterei o código do modo como ficou!!